# Need help overlaying images at specific coordinates (OpenStreetMap, OpenLayers)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I need help overlaying images over a openstreetmap map at specific coordinates.

I have this code:

```
lyr1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("Image Overlay",
            "https://www.greenique.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/test.png",
            new OpenLayers.Bounds(15.419198532265034, 47.07662635844666, 15.421042606244283, 47.07661959417825),
            new OpenLayers.Size(0, 0),
            {
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                isBaseLayer: false,
                visibility: true,
                displayInLayerSwitcher: true
            }
        );
```

and then i add it with:

```
map.addLayer(lyr1);
```

But the image does not show up anywhere on the map.
I can check/uncheck the Layer.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the bounds to openstreetmap projection and give the correct image size

```
lyr1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("Image Overlay",
            "https://www.greenique.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/test.png",
            new OpenLayers.Bounds(15.419198532265034, 47.07662635844666, 15.421042606244283, 47.07661959417825).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Size(2000, 1500),
            {
                isBaseLayer: false,
                visibility: true,
                displayInLayerSwitcher: true
            }
        );
```